# Sending `int` to constructor but compiler send `int&`

Tags: c++, class

I have:

```
//B.h
class B {
    public:
    B(int);
    //...
};

//A.h
#include "B.h"

class A {
    vector<B> vec;
    public:
    void X();
    //...
};

//A.cpp
A A::X() {
    A a;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        a.vec.push_back(B(i));     // <<< problem
    }
    return a;
}
```

And it says:

> no matching function for call to ‘B::B(int&)‘

But I don't see what's wrong here. I send `int` to `B::B`... of course just `B b = B(2);` works fine.

Edit: added `public`, sorry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What's your real code? You're missing some semicolons. The use of a header file is unnecessary in the example (just put the code in one file). We've given answers, but they probably don't solve your real problem (because you haven't posted your real code).

Comment: @Cornstalks, I'll edit, sorry.

Comment: Don't edit your code on Stack Overflow. Edit your code in your editor. Then try to compile it. Then when you get compiler errors, copy and paste the code directly from your editor to stack overflow.

Comment: @Mano What sense does it make to correct the in your question now? Isn't it solved?

Comment: @LogicStuff no, my code example I gave here was incorrect. Now this is the right one, I deleted by mistake the loop and other important details. sorry for that

Comment: @ManoMini: It's still incorrect. You are still leaving out important details.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley like what? this one is a compact version of my code. and it gives me the error I wrote.

Comment: We don't want a compact version of your code. We want your code, after you've produced an MCVE, and tried to compile it.

Comment: @Mano Firstly, you create MCVE for yourself, not for SO. You compile it before posting it, to check if the errors concur with your "real code". And then you post it with the error message (it's still not updated).

Comment: The code you've posted does not compile, with 3 trivial errors (no file `"B.h"`,  missing `#include <vector>`, `A::X` definition does not match declaration).  When you fix those, it compiles with no errors.  It won't link as there is no `main` (and no `B::B(int)`) defined, but in no way is there any problem like what you are describing.

Answer (score 3):

`B`'s constructor is `private` because the default access specifier for `class` is `private` (the default for `struct` is `public`).

`A` cannot see `B`'s constructor. Additionally, the value `x` has no value, so the code has undefined behavior.

The following code works perfectly well:

```
class B {
public:
    B(int) {}
};

class A {
    void X(); // Note X() is private.
};

void A::X() {
    int x = 42;
    B b = B(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from missing semicolons (`;`) after class definitions, and some more errors, `B`'s constructor is `private`! There's an lvalue reference in the error message that's distracting you, because you're passing an lvalue.